{SELF STUDY HOMEWORK] [IM 3] Need a hint for rewriting the ellipse equation as the circle equation.
I will copy and paste the problem in quotations.
"Since a circle is a type of ellipse it stands to reason that the ellipse equation can be rewritten into the circle equation. If this is possible, rewrite the ellipse equation into the circle equation. If it isn't, explain why".
I think this is possible but I'm not sure on how to rewrite the equations. Usually when I'm stumped on a problem I write down all my givens, so I did so but I can't make sense of how they connect. Can someone please provide a hint?
My work below: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JwIctp3nfxDfxa-k2MyxoAMeha3UYYb2/view?usp=sharing
Forgive me if this question is stupid, I'm kinda bad at math :p

Hint: A circle is an ellipse where the semi-axes are both equal.
That is, $a=b=r$.

Oh my god I didn't think of that! So that means i can replace a^2 and b^2 with r^2 then multiply both sides by r^2 to get the circle equation. Thanks a lot Eev!

That's exactly correct!
